# JavaFX problem with mouse input when drawing shapes?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, model-view-controller, paint

I've recently taken to JavaFX to produce a paint program using mouse inputs. I've come across an issue trying to put a rectangle onto my canvas - it doesn't seem to go where I want. I've spent hours trying to crack this and I think I need some help. Code is below:

The problem seems to be that the co-ordinates keep updating as I'm moving the mouse which I don't want to happen. What I want is for the user to click and drag the mouse then at the end, the rectangle will be produced based on the coordinates of mouse movement. The same thing happens with the line tool as well, as it will work just like the brush tool and more and more shapes are put down as the mouse is moved across the screen. All of this is in the controller class.

**Main Class**

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"))));
        stage.setTitle("Paint");
        stage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.File;

public class Controller {
    int prevX, prevY, startX, startY, x , y;
    boolean dragging;

    @FXML
    private Canvas canvas;

    @FXML
    private ColorPicker colorPicker;

    @FXML
    private TextField brushSize;

    @FXML
    private ToggleButton eraser;

    @FXML
    private ToggleButton line;

    @FXML
    private ToggleButton rectangle;

    public void initialize() {
        GraphicsContext g = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        canvas.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            startX = prevX = x = (int) e.getX();
            startX = prevY = y = (int) e.getY();
            dragging = true;
        });

        canvas.setOnMouseReleased(e -> {
            dragging = false;
        });

        canvas.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            double size = Double.parseDouble(brushSize.getText());
            if(!dragging)
                return;
            double x = e.getX();
            double y = e.getY();
            if(eraser.isSelected()) {
                g.clearRect(x, y, size, size);
            } else if(line.isSelected()) {
                g.strokeLine(prevX, prevY, x, y);  //                 also experiencing issues
            } else if(rectangle.isSelected()) {
                putRect(g, false, startX, startY, x, y); //           this puts the rectangle on the canvas
            } else {
                g.setStroke(colorPicker.getValue());
                g.setLineWidth(size);
                g.strokeLine(prevX, prevY, x, y);
            }
            prevX = (int) x;
            prevY = (int) y;
        });
    }

    public void putRect(GraphicsContext g, boolean filled, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) { // to create the rectangle
        if(x1 == x2 || y1 == y2) {
            return;
        } else {
            int x = Math.min(x1,x2);    // get upper left corner, (x,y)
            int y = Math.min(y1,y2);
            int w = Math.abs(x1 - x2);  // get width and height
            int h = Math.abs(y1 - y2);
            if (filled) {
                g.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
            } else {
                g.strokeRect(x, y, w, h);
            }
        }
    }

    public void onSave() {
        try{
            Image snapshot = canvas.snapshot(null, null);

            ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(snapshot, null), "png", new File("paintsave.png"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to save: " + e);
        }
    }

    public void onExit() {
        Platform.exit();
    }
}
```

**FXML**

```
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton?>
<BorderPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="600.0">

    <top>
        <VBox>
            <MenuBar>
                <Menu text="file">
                    <MenuItem text="Save" onAction="#onSave"/>
                    <MenuItem text="Exit" onAction="#onExit"/>
                </Menu>
            </MenuBar>

            <ToolBar>
                <HBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="5">
                    <TextField fx:id="brushSize" text="18"/>
                    <ColorPicker fx:id="colorPicker"/>
                    <ToggleButton fx:id="eraser" text="Eraser"/>
                    <ToggleButton fx:id="line" text="Line"/>
                    <ToggleButton fx:id="rectangle" text="Rectangle"/>
                </HBox>
            </ToolBar>
        </VBox>
    </top>

    <center>
        <Canvas fx:id="canvas" width="600" height="600"/>
    </center>

</BorderPane>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following part of the code is problematic:

```
canvas.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
  double size = Double.parseDouble(brushSize.getText());
  if(!dragging)
    return;         
  double x = e.getX();
  double y = e.getY();      
  if(eraser.isSelected()) {
    g.clearRect(x, y, size, size);
  } else if(line.isSelected()) {
    g.strokeLine(prevX, prevY, x, y);  // also experiencing issues
  } else if(rectangle.isSelected()) {
    putRect(g, false, startX, startY, x, y); // this puts the rectangle on the canvas
  } else {
    g.setStroke(colorPicker.getValue());
    g.setLineWidth(size);
    g.strokeLine(prevX, prevY, x, y);
  }
  prevX = (int) x;
  prevY = (int) y;
});
```

You see, this function is called every time that mouse is moved. That allows you seeing your line changes dinamically but introduces some additional problems. Each time that mouse is moved, new object is drawn with new coordinates, but previous object is not deleted, although it should be.

I suggest two different approaches for solving this problem:

1. Saving the coordinates of where the mouse was when this function was called last time. So, each when function is called, you should redraw the object from last time but filling it with the background color. That should act like "deleting" object you draw last time. This should work if your objects don't overlap. If they do, this could delete part of them.
2. Creating the copy of canvas before you start drawing. So, each time when function is called, reset the canvas to the state of the copy and then draw your object.

Hope something of this will work for you.